# Google maps instead of iframes

Tags: html, google-maps, object, internet-explorer-7

How to make it work in ie8-ie9?

I have used iframes, but i have to take away all the iframe and replace them with some not bug way of displaying.

This the best way which works every where except the ie7-ie9 because in IE display only empty box.

I way that I think about to take google map link and separate them between link and style, but have no idea now to do it.

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto; width:550px; height:400px;">
<object type="text/html" data="https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=BH20+5QT&amp;aq=&amp;sll=50.638194,-2.206535&amp;sspn=0.048883,0.100851&amp;t=m&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=East+Lulworth+BH20+5QT,+United+Kingdom&amp;ll=50.638085,-2.181816&amp;spn=0.021774,0.049009&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=A&amp;output=embed" style="width:550px; height:400px;">
</object></div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Displaying Google map in IE using <div> <object>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15190229/displaying-google-map-in-ie-using-div-object)

Comment: While I agree that the question body is a duplicate, the actual question does have different meaning. Not sure how you deal with that.

Comment: @Rafe   I need a way that the google map pass the validation, that's it)

Answer (score 1):

Using an object wont help much, since there are better options out there. If you cant use iframe, the best thing would be to use **Google Maps API**.

Just so I wouldn't double post, there is a way of adding a map to a page without iframes.
I have posted a response here, and the one you are looking for is in the **Solution 1** of the response.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18565736/782859

**NOTE**

The second link in the first solution contains a guide on how to add maps without iframe.