# New Google Maps embedding option

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-embed

Since the latest Google Maps update in 2013, is there a way or a resource that can be used for simple embedding Google Maps?

I have tried using the old maps system but it does not produce desired results.
Also, I have tried using Google Maps Engine, no luck there as well, because you are only served with a link to share, not embed code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After extensive research on the topic I found no simple way of embedding new Google Maps. Problem will possibly go away once Google decides to update Google Maps. However, I have not seen Google Maps development roadmap and so I can't really vouch for them.

Apart from using simple solution, there are two others (not so simple of course) that might provide a decent substitution.

---

### Solution 1

Using **[Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/)** where you can find Developer guides, API reference and code samples. There is no easy way about this, simply follow the instructions and review examples that Google has supplied. Hopefully there might be something in it that will help you.

[Simple guide to Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/fundamentals/adding-a-google-map)

---

### Solution 2

Using **[Google Maps Engine](https://mapsengine.google.com/)** will offer you a way to create your own map. Once you have created a map, added pins, points, routes, etc. at the end you can select option to *share*. However, option to share just allows you to share a link, not embed. I just wanted to point out this "feature", if you will, of the system.

To embed a map you have to click on a folder in the upper left corner. Shown on the image below and select **Embed on my site** option.

[image: Google Maps engine embed option]

Answer (score 1):

In the bottom right corner of the map you'll see a cogwheel. Click it.
Click on "Share and embed map";
Choose the size you need from the drop-down menu or choose the custom option;
Click in the box to the right that starts with `<iframe src="https://www.google` The code should be highlighted. copy and paste it into your web page or blog.

Simples!

Comment: its no longer there